# Unable to connect ethernet in ubuntu

Tags: network-manager, indicator, ethernet

Sir, I am beginner to Linux.

I have been trying to get internet access via Ethernet in my Ubuntu 11.04 but have failed to do so.

Whenever I attach ethernet cable, it starts scrolling (signaling that it has detected the Ethernet cable). But doesn't end up connecting to internet.

```
apurv@Apurv:~$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A2

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02aa]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlagn

apurv@Apurv:~$ rfkill list all

0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please add more details: What version of ubuntu you are using? The output of `lspci`? The configuration of network-manager? Anything else relevant.

Comment: My ubuntu version is 11.04. sir I am new to ubuntu. I have never used internet on unbuntu before. So please guide me how to get "output of lspi", "congiguration of network-manager".

Comment: @Apurv, open the Terminal, type `lspci` over there. Upon hitting enter you'll get a result, copy that result and using the edit option you have on the site, edit your question with the output.

Comment: Umm... 11.04 is out of commission, try upgrading to 12.04 or later so we know that is not a software problem. Use a live-cd(usb) to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have configured the router/pc with the right configurations also make sure your cable are not damaged, i had the same problem due a damaged LAN cable

Comment: sir the same wired network works fine on desktops.

Comment: actually im not sure if I can help you any more, but try connecting to different Network or pc to pc connection, this may identify the problem